# Efficient way of removing keys of certain prefix from python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a python dictionary which looks something like this;

```
{'Prefix_1':'12', 'Prefix_2':'11', 'Prefix_3':'14', '1':'241', '2':'312', '3':'421'
}
```

I want to remove the key-value pairs of those with keys that start with 'Prefix'. The result should be a dictionary that look like this;

```
{'1':'241', '2':'312', '3':'421'
}
```

My current way of doing so is to remove each pair one by one by using `del dictionary['Prefix_X']`. What are more efficient ways of doing so?

I am using python 2.7

Comment: Could you change the data structure, or how it's built? For example, if you had `{'Prefix_': {'1': '12', ...}, ...}` this becomes trivial.

Comment: This is fine too if the output dictionary remains the same.

Comment: So just do that, then: it will be much more efficient, as you only have to delete one key, although obviously there's a bit of extra work up-front.

Comment: The actual dictionary is much larger than the one in the question. There are many more keys to delete.

Comment: So? The larger the dictionary the better it is to avoid iterating over it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the other answers all use dict comprehension to create a new dict and leave the original dict untouched, I'll give one that change the dict in place:

```
for k in d.keys():
    if k.startswith('Prefix'):
        d.pop(k)
```

Is there a better way?

Let's say there are N keys in the dictionary, to find all keys with the given prefix, you'll have to iterate over all the keys, and this is of O(N) time complexity.

Then you'll need to delete them one by one, in the worst case all of them are with the given prefix, so this is also of O(N) time complexity.

The total time complexity if O(N).

Comment: Seems like this is over twice as fast as the dict comp. As long as the OP doesn't mind mutating the dict this is the way to go.

Comment: In python 3 may cause `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`, use `for k in list(d.keys()):` instead

Answer (score 3):

You could use a dict comprehension over the original dictionary:

```
D = {'Prefix_1':'12', 'Prefix_2':'11', 'Prefix_3':'14', '1':'241', '2':'312', '3':'421'

NewDict = {k: D[k] for k in D if not k.startswith('Prefix')}
NewDict
{'2': '312', '3': '421', '1': '241'}
```

Answer (score 1):

use dictionary comprehensions

```
{k:v for k, v in d.items() if not k.startswith('Prefix')}
```

---

```
In [44]: {k:v for k, v in d.items() if not k.startswith('Prefix')}
Out[44]: {'1': '241', '2': '312', '3': '421'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> z = {'Prefix_1':'12', 'Prefix_2':'11', 'Prefix_3':'14', '1':'241', '2':'312', '3':'421'}
>>> {k:v for k,v in z.items() if not k.startswith('Prefix')}
{'1': '241', '3': '421', '2': '312'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d1 = {'Prefix_1':'12', 'Prefix_2':'11', 'Prefix_3':'14', '1':'241', '2':'312', '3':'421'}
d2 = {k: v for k, v in d1.iteritems() if not k.startswith('Prefix')}

print d1
print d2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to this.

```
for key in d.keys():
    if 'Prefix' in key:
        d.pop(key)
```

Comment: This would pop the dict entry if the word 'Prefix' was not the prefix. e.g.`123Prefix`